# What will be the appropriate sentence in the given situation?

Tags: sentence-choice

From today I am going to start doing "PAN card" at my computer center. So, what will be the appropriate sentence to be written outside as a short notification ?
Can I write "PAN card is done here?" But it seems quite awkward to me.

Another center in my neighbor has written " PAN card done here" without "is".
Who is correct, I or my neighbor, or both ?
Please help, sir.

Comment: Perhaps: PAN cards are issued here.

Comment: I suggest "We do PAN cards here".